# Why does request throw an exception when crawled by googlebot but not when I paste in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, googlebot

I've been getting a ton of these exceptions in my event log.

```
EVENT ID: 1309

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 12/12/2011 1:40:41 PM 
Event time (UTC): 12/12/2011 8:40:41 PM 
Event ID: f85f113a40d349f5a1fe9ef481038281 
Event sequence: 8993 
Event occurrence: 1463 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT-1-129681577057031250 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\gouki\ 
    Machine name: GOUKIPRIME 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7508 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\gouki 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://gouki.com/Story/?page=8&orderby=views&tagged=&subject=&author=?page=10&orderby=views,views,views,&tagged=,,,,,,,,,,,,&subject=,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,&author=,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
    Request path: /Story/?page=8&orderby=views&tagged=&subject=&author= 
    User host address: 66.249.68.81 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\gouki 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 142 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\gouki 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)


Custom event details: 

Connection: Keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com
Host: gouki.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

I'm not sure where googlebot is picking up the malformed URL (I've tried to no avail to repro on my site), but what I'm more curious about is why this exception is being logged to the event log when if I copy/paste the URL myself (go on, try it), I get no error. Yeah the page is somewhat broken since the parameter values make no sense, and I can see why dual question marks could cause issues, but there is no exception thrown. I've tried changing my user agent to the googlebot, and I still don't see the error.

For some reason Asp.net MVC is seeing the first ? as part of the path and not the start of the query string, but only when googlebot is requesting the page.

Is there some sort of escaping going on here that I'm not seeing in the event log?

Comment: Might be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291307/relative-url-containing-just-the-querystring

Answer (score 2):

Notice this:

```
Request path: /Story/?page=8&orderby=views&tagged=&subject=&author=
```

The server thinks that the query string parameters is part of the page name, which probably means that the first question mark is actually escaped using `%3f`, but not shown that way in the error message. A question mark is valid as a separator for the query string, but not as part of the page name.

The bot has picked up the URL somewhere, and perhaps tried to fix it. Make sure that you have escaped the URLs properly, i.e. the `&` should be `&amp;` when the URL is in an attribute in an HTML element.

If you have a relative link like `?page=8&orderby=views&tagged=&subject=&author=` in your page, the bot might try to make a complete URL by combining it with the current page URL, which would explain the double sets of query strings. This should normally work, but if there is some problem with the escaping of the URL, it might mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

See this

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2011/08/26/a-potentially-dangerous-request-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx

Comment: Disabling the dangerous value detection doesn't seem like a good idea, though it would stop the event log spam.

Comment: You don't have any other options.

Comment: @WildJoe this "potentially dangerous query string" detection is meant to prevent misuse of development tools by novice developers. A solution developed correctly (escaped user input, no XSS and co.) will not need this preventive protection. Disabling it should be the first thing to do in a project as it prevents the solution to have nice query strings.