# Making a csv file from a html button

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out how to make a csv file when pressing a button, a similar button already exists on the site I am working on but I do not understand the logic behind the redirection, this is what the button that works looks like with it's href:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-export" href="?csv=1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Exporter {{pages.total}} élément(s)"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></a>
```

Could anyone please explain to me how this href can call any particular function or is this an export mode maybe? I'm not sure, any help is greatly appreciated and I will gladly give you guys more info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative URL containing just the querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291307/relative-url-containing-just-the-querystring)

Comment: Oh, thank you I understand how a relative URL works now, I just need to figure out how the csv part works, if it's either a function that we created or a pre existing one, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an HTTP URL, a `?` indicates the start of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

A relative URL consisting entirely of a query string will keep the current path and replace any existing query string with the new one.

e.g. if the current URL is `http://example.com/myData.php` then the link will resolve to `http://example.com/myData.php?csv=1`.

Server side code can then process the query string to output different data to the previous URL (which didn't have a query string).

Comment: Alright, that's great thank you for explaining this to me I had no idea that this was what happened! Thank you very much

Comment: I do have one more question, I found the query get request in my code and it looked like this: ```if request.args.get("csv"):``` but why is there a =1 at the end of the href? does this have any specific reason?